# How to filter in ngTables

Tags: angularjs, filter, ngtable

```
<td style="text-align: center" title="'NUMBER' | translate" 
filter="{callRoute:{number:'text'}}" {{quece.callRoute.number}}</td>
```

I want filter in ng-Tabel but it's not working

Comment: Post more information to understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this buddy :

```
 filter="'quece.callRoute.number' : text}" {{quece.callRoute.number}}
```

If you have nested properties you want to filter you should enclose their name in single quotes.

Comment: You are welcome @majid . If my reply suits your needs remember to mark it as correct. :)